# Object not serializable error while reading multiple AVRO files

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, avro

I am trying to merge small avro files from a HDFS directory into a single file. Can someone guide me on how to merge them using scala-spark. Thanks in advance.

The below shown code creates an RDD using the newAPIHadoopFile method.

```scala
val src = "/hdfs/path/to/folder"
val rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(src, classOf[AvroKeyInputFormat[GenericRecord]], classOf[AvroKey[GenericRecord]], classOf[NullWritable], sc.hadoopConfiguration)
```

It is giving me the below error that tells me that I am doing something wrong:

```
scala> rdd.take(1).foreach(println)
19/07/16 07:28:59 WARN AvroKeyInputFormat: Reader schema was not set. Use AvroJob.setInputKeySchema() if desired.
19/07/16 07:28:59 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2)
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroKey
Serialization stack:
        - object not serializable (class: org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroKey, value: {someValue})
        - field (class: scala.Tuple2, name: _1, type: class java.lang.Object)
        - object (class scala.Tuple2, (someValue,(null)))
        - element of array (index: 0)
        - array (class [Lscala.Tuple2;, size 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not concerned about rdd easier way to do the same would be using Spark Dataframe.For Spark 2+ Code would look something like this

```scala
val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
val inputAvro = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load("/hdfs/path/to/folder")
inputAvro.coalesce(partitionNumber).write.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").save("<outputPath>")
```

Here `partitionNumber` would be number of files that you would want to write the avro to

While running this code you have to include `--packages com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:4.0.0` to ensure that it picks up the avro reader

Comment: Thank you for the instant reply. But the thing is the files I have, do not have the ".avro" extension and hence the databricks package doesn't work. Would really be helpful if you can suggest some other way.

Comment: Hmm that seems weird. How is the header constructed. Looking at the code and the exception that you have, the header seems to be a problem

Comment: @tavish There's a configurable parameter to read files not ending in Avro extension

Comment: There's no need to use `com.databricks.spark.avro` from Spark `2.4.0` onwards; it's baked in and can be used via `format("avro")`.

Comment: @cricket_007 Yup, thanks found it. 
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("avro.mapred.ignore.inputs.without.extension", "false")

Comment: @BenWatson I am using 2.3 sadly. Thanks anyways. Good to know that! :)